Homotopy exact sequence of a covering map
I wanted to compute a homotopy group using the homotopy exact sequence of a covering but I am missing something obvious.
Consider the covering $\mathbb{C} - \{0, \pm 1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} - \{0, 1\},\  z\mapsto z^2.$ This is a normal covering because the deck transformations $z \mapsto \pm z$ act transitively on the fiber. The group of deck transformations is $\pm 1$, the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C} - \{0, \pm 1\}$ is $F_3$, the free group on three generates, and the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C} - \{0, \pm 1\}$ is $F_2$. The homotopy exact sequence should read
$$
1 \rightarrow F_3 \rightarrow F_2 \rightarrow \pm 1 \rightarrow 1.
$$
I do not think this is true, because the covering map maps a loop around $\pm 1$ to a loop around $1$. Thus the map $F_3 \rightarrow F_2$ should not be injective.
Please, can someone explain the mistake.
Edit: Here is the reply. The homotopy exact sequence is completely correct. However, the loops around $\pm1$ are mapped to loops around $1$ which are conjugate by an element that does not lie in the image of $F_3 \rightarrow F_2$ (in my computation it was the loop around zero - only the loop which goes twice around zero is in the image).
Thank you for your replies.

You are making a mistake in the last paragraph. If you want to identify the exact nature of the mistake, you should provide more detail.

What you might be overlooking is that in order to specify the first homotopy group of a space $X$ you must choose a base point $p \in X$. The group $\pi_1(X,p)$ is then represented by loops that are based at the point $p$.
Now let's go to your setting where $X = \mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\}$ and where $T : \mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\} \to \mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\}$ is the deck transformation for the 2--1 covering map $\mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\} \to \mathbb C - \{0,1\}$. In this setting, indeed in any setting where you have a nontrivial deck transformation, $T$ fixes no point of $X$. So whatever base point $p \in \mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\}$ you choose in order to specify the group $\pi_1(\mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\},p)$,

The deck transformation $T$ does not fix $p$.
Loops based at $p$ are not mapped to loops based at $p$.
From a group theoretic perspective, the deck transformation $T$ does not act on $\pi_1(\mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\},p)$.


Now, it is absolutely correct to say that $T$ maps a loop around $1$ to a loop around $-1$ (assuming the covering map is appropriately chosen).
But keep in mind, these are unbased loops, they do not represent elements of $\pi_1(\mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\},p) \approx F_3$.
What you can do in this situation is to make use of the fact that unbased loops in $\mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\}$ represent conjugacy classes of the group $\pi_1(\mathbb C - \{0,\pm 1\},p)$. So you can make the conclusion that the injective homomorphism $F_3 \mapsto F_2$ induces a non-injective function from the set of conjugacy classes of $F_3$ to the set of conjugacy classes of $F_2$. There is no contradiction in this statement.
